# SSRS Report Shows a White Space In Textboxes for NULL Values But I Want an Empty String Instead

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a grid with a lot of rows and columns to display data for a report.

Each cell in the grid is represented by a textbox and I am trying to show a blank or empty string in my textboxes to represent a NULL values instead of the default white space. The reason behind is that each textbox value has been underlined to show to the user that it is a link they can click on. A white space in the cell now represents an underscore and replacing the whitespace by blank or an empty string should hopefully solve the issue.

Answers on stackoverflow suggest to set the visibility of the textbox to false but I don't want to do this because this would hide the cell in the grid and I want to show the cells (empty cell with borders).

Here is the code I use to attempt to replace Nothing by an empty string but it doesn't work:

```
=IIf(IsNothing(Fields!HattyAppsLateOver60.Value),"",Fields!HattyAppsLateOver60.Value)
```

I have tried using the Trim() method but that doesn't work either.

Is there a way to globally make white spaces show as an empty string or is there a method I could use in my expression to solve my issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use something like the following expression to drive the TextDecoration property:

=IIf( Fields!HattyAppsLateOver60.Value <> "", "Underline", "Default"  )

Comment: Thank you Mike! I was thinking about doing this too but I was hoping there would be a way to remove the white space instead. I wanted to mention as a side note a more generic way of accessing the text box value. I had to update more than a 100 text boxes each using a different field and using the following expression allowed me to do a quick search and replace. =IIf(Me.Value <> "","Underline","Default") This expression will also be beneficial in case the expression on the Value is changed down the road.

Comment: Actually Me.Value might not be reliable. It doesn't seem to work in SSRS2012 and it was also a problem in the past as per this post here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/98f0e6a0-108c-44bb-8730-5e90cf1fa5a4/mevalue-bug-in-ssrs-2008 (It is supposed to work in SSRS2005 and SSRS2008R2)

Comment: Thank you again for your help. I ended up not using the Me.Value because SSRS2012 doesn't seem to understand it. It could be some new bug introduced by Microsoft as it happened between the 2005 and 2008 versions of SSRS.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just modify your query to have something like:

select field1, field2, coalesce(field3,''), field4 
from myTable 
where condition=true

The coalesce function takes multiple parameters and will return the first non-null value.  So you could do something like Coalesce(field1, field2, field3, '') terminating with an empty string to make sure that you guarantee at least one of the options has a non-NULL value.

Comment: I also do this while in SQL to remove whitespace since the trim function doesn't work on it:

REPLACE(cd.[Description], NCHAR(0x00A0), '')